# Collapse React Sidebar using Hooks

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, sidebar

I need to collapse my Sidebar base on screen size. So far I was not lucky with all my attempts. I was wondering if someone could give me some tips about that by using Hooks.
The status is set to "isOpen={true}" and I need to make it false when reached width 768px or lower.

Thanks in advance

```
 return (
    <div className="menu-bar">
      <Menu
        width={210}
        isOpen={true}
        noOverlay
        noTransition
        pageWrapId={"page-wrap"}
        outerContainerId={"outer-container"}
        customBurgerIcon={false}
        customCrossIcon={false}
        disableAutoFocus
        disableCloseOnEsc
      >
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This custom hook uses [`Window.matchMedia()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia) to return a Boolean according to the query passed:

```js
const { useMemo, useState, useEffect } = React

const useMediaQuery = query => {
  const mql = useMemo(() => window.matchMedia(query))

  const [match, setMatch] = useState(mql.matches)

  useEffect(() => {
    const handler = e => setMatch(e.matches)
    mql.addListener(handler)
    
    return () => {
      mql.removeListener(handler)
    }
  }, [mql])
  
  return match
}

const Demo = () => {
  const close = useMediaQuery('(max-width: 600px)')
  
  return (
    <div className="container">
      {close || <aside />}
      <main />
    </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Demo />,
  root
)
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  height: 75vh;
}

main {
  flex: 4;
  height: 100%;
  background: purple;
}

aside {
  flex: 1;
  height: 100%;
  background: gold;
}
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a minified example:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [isNavOpen, setIsNavOpen] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("resize", () => {
      if (window.innerWidth <= 768) {
        setIsNavOpen(false)
      }
    })
    return window.removeEventListener("resize", () => {
      if (window.innerWidth <= 768) {
        setIsNavOpen(false)
      }
    })
  })

  return (
    <div className="nav">
      <Nav isOpen{isNavOpen}/>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: You have to use the same function for add/remove event listener. Extract the function and use it both add and remove. In addition, set an empty dependency list on the `useEffect()`, because it doesn't have any dependency, and can run on mount.